# How to have my Win32 program 'pin to taskbar'?

Tags: c, windows

I've written a small Win32 program in C which compiles and runs exactly as designed except for one thing...

When I run the program, the icon appears in the taskbar as expected. However, I cannot 'right click' on the running icon and select 'pin this program to the taskbar' - that option does not appear. The only right click option I have is to close the program.

How does one create a win32 program that allows the 'pin to taskbar' option?

Comment: p.s. I've spent that past several days searching the internet for an answer to this before posting the question - there's lots of discussion about taskbars, but none that answer this specific question that I've found.

Comment: Did you check the list at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/be07deba-8b05-4752-922c-91bcd2a98445 ?

Comment: I had a look today. Other than a name that's not the best "Win32TedDlgApp.exe", the program does not actually fail any of the tests in that FAQ. It also only appears in the registry where it should (in some history lists for the editor and in active tasks).

Answer (score 3):

Credit for this answer goes to Okkaaj.

To pin a win32 compiled executable to the taskbar, the executable file must reside on a local hard drive. Executing from a remote network drive prevents the file from being pinned to the taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

I would have commented, but because I don't have 50 reputation - I had to make an answer.

I don't believe it's because of your application. 
I just made a simple Win32 C application, and the pinning works just fine. Try to check under this registry key: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]` and delete the entry "NoPinningToTaskbar" if it's present. Although if your applications name is any of the names mentioned in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation\AddRemoveNames` it might be the reason it cannot be pinned. Hopefully you can get it solved.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately 'NoPinningToTaskbar' was not set,  and the file name is not listedin 'AddRemoveNames' either. It was a very hopeful try, but in the end did not  work for me.

Comment: That's weird. Is the executable on a network location or on a local drive? If it's on a network location, execute it from local drive and see if you're able to pin it. You could also check  'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\<exename>', if it exists - you can try to remove it. If either one of those won't work, then I don't know what could cause it. Good luck though.

Comment: That was it! Thanks very much. The executable was created and compiled on a remote network drive. When I copied the executable to a local drive and ran it I was immediately able to pin it to the taskbar. "Executable must be on local hard drive" should be part of the Microsoft docs on pinning programs to the task bar.